# Best way to count how much time user spend on your app (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, time

**I want to count the time that the user spent in my app then store it and when the user uses the app again we add the new time**

there are multiple activities in my app and I'm using MVVM so I think it's best to put the logic in the MVVM

the problem is how to count time

any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view's `onStart()` tell the view model to start counting time, and in `onStop()` tell it to stop and persist it.

In the view model, when told to start counting time, store the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a property. When told to stop, subtract that value from another call to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and persist it to the model by adding it to the previously recorded value retrieved from the model.

*Edit based on comment:*

Here's how you can use a coroutine to create a counter that updates a LiveData periodically. Since delays in coroutines aren't perfectly precise, I have it fire four times a second to prevent the timer from noticeably losing or gaining a second from time to time.

```
private val _secondsUpTime = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val secondsUpTime: LiveData<Int> = _secondsUpTime

private var startTime = -1L
private var counterJob: Job? = null

fun notifyAppStarted() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    counterJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        val lastPersistedLifetime = repo.lifetimeMillis
        while (true) {
            val totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime + lastPersistedLifetime
            _secondsUpTime.value = (totalTime / 1000).toInt()
            delay(250)
        }
    }
}

fun notifyAppStopped() {
    if (startTime < 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Tried to notify app stopped without notifying app started first.")
        return
    }
    counterJob?.cancel()
    val totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime + repo.lifetimeMillis
    repo.lifetimeMillis = totalTime // persist to the repository
}
```

Comment: isn't there any better way I mean it counts in millies isn't there in seconds or minutes

Comment: Just divide by 1000?

Comment: is there a way to make live data of the time because I'm doing some operations on time while user in the app so I need to make like infinite loop ask for the time that the user spent

Comment: is it ok if I just make a while(true) loop ask for time and update live data for each minute

Comment: You mean instead of launching a coroutine? If you do it without a coroutine or with posted delays on the main thread, you will freeze your app because the function will not release the thread. You can change the delay in the coroutine to something like 5000 if you only want to show updates every minute.